Specifying exact placement of answers in exam tests
I would like to make exam tests that can be compiled without and with answers, and the answers should be placed exactly in the empty spaces between the questions. That is, everything except from the answers should overlap in the two  compiled pdf files. All questions and answers are inserted from separate input files (each question/answer pair is written in a unique text file). The document looks like this:
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{etoolbox} % to set up conditional for without and with answers version
\newtoggle{wta}  % with answers
\toggletrue{wta} % turn on/true wta/with answers, by default it is false

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\input{question01.tex}
\input{question02.tex}
% ... etc.
\input{question40.tex}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}

And questions look like this:
\item\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{
Question part (4-6 lines of text)

\iftoggle{wta}{
Answer part; should be placed between the questions without changing the overall layout and placement of the questions.
}
{\vspace*{3cm}} % the space before the next question
}

The above code is simplified because I tried to make an MWE.
Is this feasible and if yes, how?

I would encourage you to look into the exam document class. You may start with: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Typesetting_exams_in_LaTeX.
See Section 7 and 8 of the documentation for details regarding placing empty space for answers.

You can use \noindent\parbox[c][3cm][c]{\linewidth}{The answer goes here} to vertically center the ansewr in the 3cm space.  You can use \centering inside the parbox if you want that as well.

OK, I figured it out how can I solve this. CodeR's comment on the exam package helped.
I insert 2 parboxes with the same heights, one is empty, the other has the answer. This makes sure that both documents will have the same layout. The questions look like this:
\item\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{
Question part (4-6 lines of text)

\iftoggle{wta}{% answer, used when wta is set to true
\parbox[t][3cm][c]{\linewidth}{
Answer...
}
}
{\parbox[t][3cm][t]{\linewidth}{}}% Empty box, used when wta is set to false
}

